# How to change num_threads in Startup.jl on Windows (Julia)

Tags: multithreading, julia

I am trying to run my code in parallel (CPU has 8 cores) and wanted to automatically have julia startup with 8 threads. I went to `C:\Users\chris\.julia\config` and created a `startup.jl` file that only contains one line:

```
JULIA_NUM_THREADS = 8
```

When starting Julia and then checking with `Threads.nthreads()`, it still only shows 1 thread. I know the file is read upon startup, because it throws an error if I write any nonsense into it.
I also tried `ENV["JULIA_NUM_THREADS"] = 8`, but that did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a note about this in the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/environment-variables/#JULIA_NUM_THREADS):

> **Note:**
>
> `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` must be defined before starting julia; defining it in startup.jl is too late in the startup process.

So you have to set things up from outside Julia. Depending how you start Julia:

- if you are using VS code, you can change the number of threads in the settings of the Julia extension
- if you are running julia from the command-line, you can set the `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` environment variable globally (using the Windows configuration panel, or setting it in your `.bashrc`/`.profile` file if you're using Linux)

Comment: Ah - the windows configuration panel - sorry for being a little slow on the uptake, I have never used Linux (stone me now) and a lot of the discourse Julia pages seem to focus on such users. For Windows, its "Edit the system environment variables">"Environment Variables">"System variables". Hit "New", and then just put JULIA_NUM_THREADS as variable names and variable value as 8.

Answer (score 0):

I've just add the variable to `Environment Variables` like below. It works fine.

[image]